# Why does an upgrade from OpenSuSE Leap 15.4 to 15.5 lead to a downgrade of PostgreSQL, vim, and some other packages?

Tags: opensuse, postgresql, zypper

When upgrading my homelab from OpenSuSE Leap 15.4 (x86_64) to 15.5 by using `zypper --releasever=15.4 dup --download-in-heaps`, I am told to confirm a downgrade a bunch of packages, most (but not all) of which belonging to the PostgreSQL universe:

```
  bind bind-doc bind-utils cups-filters hplip hplip-hpijs hplip-sane kbd kbd-legacy libheif1 libnftables1
  libpq5 libraw20 libsigc-2_0-0 libsource-highlight4 nftables postgresql12 postgresql12-contrib
  postgresql12-llvmjit postgresql12-server postgresql13 postgresql13-contrib postgresql13-llvmjit
  postgresql13-server postgresql14 postgresql14-contrib postgresql14-llvmjit postgresql14-server python3-bind
  python3-nftables python3-packaging systemd-rpm-macros ucode-intel vim vim-data vim-data-common
```

What makes this downgrade necessary? And: Will it lead to trouble when using PostgreSQL?